# How to get IP address of WebRTC peer in IPFS / libp2p?

Tags: ipfs, libp2p, js-ipfs

I'm using this code to play around with IPFS in the browser. I'm wondering how I can access the ip addresses of the webRTC peers? or even know if the peers are actually webRTC, or http peers?

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ipfs/dist/index.min.js"></script>

<script>
    (async () => {
        window.node = await Ipfs.create({
          config: {
            Addresses: {
              Swarm: []
            },
            Bootstrap: []
          }
        })
        window.node.libp2p.on('peer:discovery', (peer) => console.log('peer:discovery', peer))
        window.node.libp2p.on('peer:connect', peerInfo => console.log('peer:connect', peerInfo))
        window.node.libp2p.on('peer:disconnect', peerInfo => console.log('peer:disconnect', peerInfo))
        window.node.libp2p.peerStore.on('peer', (peerId) => console.log('peer', peerId))
        window.node.libp2p.peerStore.on('change:multiaddrs', ({ peerId, multiaddrs}) => console.log('change:multiaddrs', {peerId, multiaddrs}))
        window.node.libp2p.peerStore.on('change:protocols', ({ peerId, protocols}) => console.log('change:protocols', {peerId, protocols}))
        window.node.libp2p.on('error', (err) => console.log('error', err))
        window.node.libp2p.connectionManager.on('peer:connect', (connection) => console.log('peer:connect', connection))
        window.node.libp2p.connectionManager.on('peer:disconnect', (connection) => console.log('peer:disconnect', connection))

        const data = 'Hello'
        const results = await window.node.add(data)
        console.log({results})
    })()

</script>
```

`node.swarm.peers()` gives me a list of peers, but it doesn't seem to include the IP address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your config, it seems that you did not configure any swarm address. A swarm address must be configured for your peer to be diable from other peers in the network.

Some context, in this specific case, you are dealing with a browser environment. Currently, Browsers do not allow listening for connections. One of the limitations is actually that a browser does not provide an "IP Address" that someone can use to reach to it. They are designed in a client-server model where the server IP Address is known and the client will establish the connection with it.

As one of the ways to solve the issue above, there is [libp2p-webrtc-star](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p-webrtc-star) transport. It basically uses a server that will be responsible for listening for connections on behalf of browser nodes. You can use one of the available servers for experimenting https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p-webrtc-star#hosted-rendezvous-server. Basically, you should add to your swarm addresses, a multiaddr such as `/dns4/wrtc-star1.par.dwebops.pub/tcp/443/wss/p2p-webrtc-star`. Once your node starts, your browser node will establish a connection with the server and the server will inform all the other peers about the peer who joined. These peers can dial your peer via this star server and the multiaddrs will look something like: `/dns4/wrtc-star1.par.dwebops.pub/tcp/443/wss/p2p-webrtc-star/p2p/QmSoLPppuBtQSGwKDZT2M73ULpjvfd3aZ6ha4oFGL1KrGM`.

With this setup, you should be able to open multiple browsers and peers discover and connect to each other. If you run the `ipfs.swarm.peers` you should see the addresses of the other nodes peers via the star server.

I hope this helps you move forward. I also highly recommend you to check the following examples:

- https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/tree/master/examples/browser-exchange-files
- https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/blob/master/examples/libp2p-in-the-browser

As a complement, there are a few new features being worked on that aim to improve the browser experience in this regard. You can follow the developments on: https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/issues/703

Comment: so if I understand correctly, the peers in swarm.peers I am not connected to yet, and that is why their IP address is not visible. If I add or get some data, then the webRTC connection will occur and I should be able to see IP addresses?

Comment: Yes, you are not connected yet with them. You will be able to see their multiaddrs in the swarm.peers. The data should be unrelated with all the networking part for establishing the connection. You don't need to do it to establish the connections. The console.log attached to the events should be triggered once you open multiple browsers

Comment: that makes sense, so if I try getting a CID, does the star server ever needs to know the CID? or will it just connect me to a random peer, and then I will ask this random peer for a CID, and so on, and the star server never knows what CID I want.

Comment: When we talk about content, we talk about content routing, that is how a peer will find content on the network. If you are connected with the peer, you should be able to find the content. However, if you are not connected to it your node needs to use a content routing mechanism. There are currently two modules that can be used for content routing https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/blob/master/doc/CONFIGURATION.md#content-routing . The DHT in JS is still not stable and we will work on improving it over the next few months. (... continue in next answer)

Comment: The delegate routing leverages another peer with better capabilities to crawl the network. In a browser node, it is highly recommended at this moment to use this method, as it can leverage a go-ipfs node with a more efficient DHT underneath. js-ipfs already comes with delegates enabled by default for a smoother experience, as you can see in https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/packages/ipfs/src/core/runtime/config-browser.js#L9 . If you go to production, it is important to deploy your own.

With all this, I believe that you will be able to fetch content transparently